# Is it possible to write a C program without using header files?

Tags: c

Is it possible to write a C program without using header files? If it is, how?

Comment: Do you mean in an environment with a standard library, i.e. an OS, or running on bare metal, e.G. a kernel or boot loader?

Comment: @Cody I meant is he trying to assume the contents of stdio.h etc. AFAICR that's not possible because it's permissable for any of the functions to be a macro and so even if you write out the printf signature from the standard there may not actually be a _printf underneath to link against, etc., because the standard library might have macroed it away.

Comment: This is evidently a common homework or interview question, as it's been asked and answered many, many times on various forums: http://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=can+a+c+program+be+possible+without+using+header+file&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=vZJKTdO-HITPgAf-n6VI

Answer (score 16):

Of course:

```
int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

Or even:

```
int printf(const char *format, ... ); // could be copied from stdio.h

int main() {
   printf("Hello, world!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

The `#include` directive effectively just includes the header file's content in the source file.

Answer (score 4):

Of course.

A header file is just a file that gets included in some source files, and when you include a file you just copy its content.

You can write any program you want to without any `#include`, but you'd have to manually put the stuff you need in your source files.

Comment: I think there is a large section of people that do not realize this. "An Eye opener" that's what I would call this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to write a simple program without header files, but why would you do that ?

Header files are useful to share definitions, constants, functions prototypes, etc between multiple files or modules.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Because header files written in C. But it's hard.

`printf` example:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

`scanf` example:

```
int scanf(const char *format, ...);
```

and more...

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely yes, you can even inlinme the function prototype you possibly need in the c file itself

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to write the shortest code possible in c, so i tried removing the header files from source code.To my surprise even a program with printf compiled with just a warning and ran successfully.How does that happen??

main()
{
   printf("Hello World\n");
}

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but by all means, avoid from not using it if not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can wirte a program without #include , but it will increase the complexity of the programmer means user have to write down all the functions manually he want to use.It takes a lot of time and careful attention while write long programs.Yes ,simple program like given above have no problem to write without including any library function call.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<"filename">
```

will help you to implement and use the functions present in the file, 
i.e.

```
#include< stdio.h>
```

will help us to use the built functions present in the `stdio.h` file  - `printf` and `scanf`

When you dont use `#include< stdio.h>` in your program , it still will not cause any problems, its only when you may use printf or scanf it may cause the program to generate a warning at the time of compilation (for implicit declaration of function `printf`.)

More Details on the same , Below link is the screenshot for the same for the printf used without specifying `#include<stdio.h>`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE9w3.png)